# The index unused when apply transform

Tags: html, css

[demo](https://codepen.io/zhos/pen/bgepwm)
I want to translate the first `div`, when hovered.

But the tag `span` covered by the second `div`. I do not know why.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things are contributing to your problem:

`z-index` is not a `px` based number, [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index).

Update your `z-index` to `z-index:-90;` from `z-index:-90px;`

`id`'s cannot start with a number, [see this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/648350).

Update your div to `id="div2"` from `id="2div"`

**[Updated Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggMrjB)**